# How can I filter a vector on an index in Rust

Tags: rust

I have a `Vec<f64>` and I am trying to get say every 7th element of the vector till I run out of bounds, into another `Vec<f64>`. I thought maybe I could create an index of the elements I want and then filter based on that. But I can't seem to be able to do this directly or indirectly. What I tried

```
let x: Vec<f64> = (1..200)
.map(|x| (x as f64)/(200 as f64))
.collect();

let y: Vec<f64> = x
.enumerate()
.filter(|&(i, _)| i % 7 == 0 )
.map(|(_, e)| e)
.collect();
```

But this did not work with compile error `enumerate method cannot be called on Vec<f64> due to unsatisfied trait bounds`. I also found a retain method but don't see a way to apply it on the index rather than the element. A robust search of SO surprisingly did not yield anything.

Comment: "Did not work" How? A compile-time error? A runtime error? Show the full error. Unexpected results? Explain what were the expected results and what you got.

Comment: `.iter().enumerate()`

Comment: @Dogbert I think `.into_iter()` (or `.iter().copied()`) in this case.

Comment: I also tried `.iter().enumerate()`. It shows no error, but it enumerates the iterator itself as a single element and index zero!!!

Comment: Please always show the full error from `cargo check`. Regardless, @Dogbert is right.

Comment: Had you used a slice the compiler would suggest you "`[f64]` is not an iterator; try calling `.iter()`". Should work for `Vec` too. I guess I will send a PR soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the comments, patching everything together into a more complete answer for the community. Let's say this is the Vec: `let x: Vec<f64> = (1..10).map(|x| (x as f64)/(10 as f64)).collect();`

To filter the vector based on index, first we create an iterator with into_iter, then enumerate it to get index, then apply the filter, and then a map to remove the index, finally collecting it to f64 vector.

```
let y: Vec<f64> = x
.into_iter()
.enumerate()
.filter(|&(i, _)| i % 2 == 0 )
.map(|(_, e)| e)
.collect();
```

If the scope of `y` is shorter than that of `x`, and if you had large values in `y` (say string), it might be preferable to make `y` a vector of references rather than values.

```
let y: Vec<&f64> = x
.iter()
.enumerate()
.filter(|&(i, _)| i % 2 == 0 )
.map(|(_, e)| e)
.collect();
```

The key difference here is using `iter()` instead of `into_iter()`. [This page](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-02-iterators.html) in rust book explains it:

> The iter method produces an iterator over immutable references. If we
> want to create an iterator that takes ownership of v1 and returns
> owned values, we can call `into_iter` instead of `iter`. Similarly, if we
> want to iterate over mutable references, we can call `iter_mut` instead
> of `iter`.

Now, for this specific question, applying a filter to the index is probably not needed. A simpler way, as noted by Chayim below is

```
let y: Vec<_> = x.into_iter().step_by(2).collect();
```

Comment: Note that if you don't have another reason for the intermediate `Vec`, you can get rid of `x`, the first `collect` and the `into_iter` an just chain the iterators directly: `let y = (1..10).map(…).enumerate().filter(…).map(…).collect::<Vec<_>>()`.

Comment: Also you can replace the `.filter(…).map(…)` with `.filter_map (|(i, e)| if (i % 2) == 0 { Some (e) } else { None })` or even with `.filter_map (|(i, e)| ((i % 2) == 0).then (|| Some (e)))`.

Answer (score 2):

Note that there is a specialized iterator adapter for that, [`step_by()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.step_by):

```rust
let y: Vec<_> = x.into_iter().step_by(7).collect();
```

Answer (score 1):

> I also found a retain method but don't see a way to apply it on the index rather than the element.

While `Vec::retain` does not give you any sort of index, it takes an `FnMut` and is documented to operate in-order:

> This method operates in place, **visiting each element exactly once in the original order**, and preserves the order of the retained elements.

So you can just keep track of the index yourself:

```
let mut idx = 0;
x.retain(|_| {
    let v = idx;
    idx += 1;
    v % 2 == 0
});
```

Or here you can specialise with a simple toggle:

```
let mut keep = false;
x.retain(|_| {
    keep = !keep;
    keep
});
```